# how to solve a quadratic diophanic equation on integers and obtain various results

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

This quadratic di  equation has more results, as it came to them.

I can only think of this

```
FindInstance[(4 p + 3 q - 2) (p - 1) == (6 p + 2 q) q, {p,  q}, Integers]
```

Comment: You can add a number at the end of `FindInstance` to request more solutions: `FindInstance[(4 p + 3 q - 2) (p - 1) == (6 p + 2 q) q, {p,  q}, PositiveIntegers, 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 12, assuming positive integers

```
sol1 = Solve[(4 p + 3 q - 2) (p - 1) == (6 p + 2 q) q, {p, q}, 
   PositiveIntegers] // Simplify
```

[image]

For earlier versions with the same assumption,

```
sol2 = Solve[{(4 p + 3 q - 2) (p - 1) == (6 p + 2 q) q, p > 0, q > 0}, {p, q},
    Integers] // Simplify
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, set upper and lower bounds on `p` and `q`. For example,

```
sol3 = Solve[{(4 p + 3 q - 2) (p - 1) == (6 p + 2 q) q, -1000 < p < 
    1000, -1000 < q < 1000}, {p, q}, Integers]

(* {{p -> -143, q -> -123}, {p -> -143, q -> 336}, {p -> -76, 
  q -> -66}, {p -> -6, q -> 14}, {p -> -3, q -> -4}, {p -> -3, 
  q -> 7}, {p -> 0, q -> -2}, {p -> 1, q -> -3}, {p -> 1, q -> 0}, {p -> 5, 
  q -> -12}, {p -> 5, q -> 3}, {p -> 18, q -> 14}, {p -> 28, 
  q -> -66}, {p -> 105, q -> -247}, {p -> 105, q -> 88}, {p -> 621, q -> 527}} *)
```

Comment: in sol1, says positive integers, why do they appear real too?

Comment: Why do you think they are not integers? Look at specific values for `C[1]`, for example, `Table[sol1 /. C[1] -> c1, {c1, 1, 3}] // Simplify`

Comment: ,Sorry I didn't notice. Thanks